# Prove by in induction

Tags: logic, proof-writing, induction

I am new to symbolic logic, and I know the basis of proving by induction. I need help with this question.

Consider the function ! : LA → N defined recursively as follows:

1. α! = 0, for any atomic sentence α
2. (¬φ)! = φ!
3. (φ∧ψ)!=φ!+ψ!+1

Now consider the function ∗ : LA → N defined recursively as
follows:

1. α∗ = 1, for any atomic sentence α
2. (¬φ)∗ = φ∗
3. (φ ∧ ψ)∗ = φ∗ + ψ∗
   Prove, by induction on the complexity of φ, that φ∗ = φ! + 1.

So to start up my base case for my prove is the stating that α! = 0 and α∗ = 1.
My inductive hypothesis (which I am not sure is correct) is φ∗ = φ! + 1.
for my inductive steps:

Adding φ∗ + φ! we have φ∗+φ! = φ∗+φ!, by using our base case α! = 0 and α∗ = 1, we have φ∗+0 = φ!+1 therefore, φ∗ = φ!+1

I know it is really poor proving, so could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the ! function counts the number of intersection symbols, while the * function counts the number of atoms?

Comment: Hi @ShyPerson, I am not really sure.

Comment: Try several examples of each to see if my guess is correct.

Comment: @ShyPerson I will, but my main concern is writing the proof rather than focusing on the functions themselves, could you help me with the proving?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much mathematical training, but I think the following should be roughly correct.

It looks like $(\phi)!$ counts the number of binary connectives and $(\phi)*$ the number of atomic subformulas of $\phi$. So, intuitively, $(\phi)* = (\phi)! + 1$ should hold.

The proof is by induction on the complexity of formulas:

Base Case: $\phi$ is atomic. Then $(\phi)* = 1$ and $(\phi)! = 0$ by the definition of $!$ and $*$. Hence, $(\phi)* = 1 = (\phi)! + 1$.

Induction Case: First, consider the case where $\phi$ of the form $\neg \psi$. The induction hypothesis gives us $(\psi)* = (\psi)! + 1$. And, by definition, adding a negation to $\psi$ leaves the value of both $!$ and $*$ untouched. Hence, $(\phi)* =  (\phi)! + 1$.

Next, consider the case where $\phi$ of the form $\psi \land \chi$. The induction hypothesis gives us $(\psi)* = (\psi)! + 1$ and $(\chi)* = (\chi)! + 1$. Now, $(\phi)* = (\psi)* + (\chi)* = (\psi)! + (\chi)! + 2 = (\phi)! +1$ where the first equality is by the definition of $*$, the second by induction hypothesis, and the third by the definition of $!$.